# wxPython Splashscreen on loading

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to show a splash screen as soon as possible while my app is importing by doing something like this

```
import wx, wx.lib.agw.advancedsplash as AS, sys, os, matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from threading import Thread

#some function definitions

class application(wx.Frame):
  #the UI code here

class mod(Thread):
  #blah blah

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = wx.App(redirect=True, filename="logfile.txt")

  image = wx.Image("splash.png")
  image.ConvertAlphaToMask()
  bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
  splash = AS.AdvancedSplash(None, bitmap=bitmap, timeout=4000, agwStyle=AS.AS_TIMEOUT | AS.AS_CENTER_ON_SCREEN)

  import time
  import telnetlib
  import ownmodule
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
  from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx as NavigationToolbar
  from matplotlib.figure import Figure

  frame = application(None, -1, "AdvancedSplash Test")
  app.MainLoop()
```

but the only thing I get is the shape in gray of the image I chose, then the UI loads and the actual image fills up the gray shape in a flash and disappears timed out. It's like the splash screen shows but the image doesn't load until the main frame does.

What it should happen is to show immediately the image, not only the shape. Somebody know what is happening and how to solve it?

Also it would be great to not time out the splash screen but destroy it right before the main UI appears.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `MainLoop` is not running then there is no way for events to be delivered to the window, including the splashscreen's `EVT_PAINT` event that will draw the bitmap.

The `wx.Yield` function will run a temporary event loop so adding a call to that after creating the splashscreen will let it paint itself and may  be sufficient for your needs. One downside is that if there needs to be another paint event while you are doing your other startup code then it won't happen unless you do another `wx.Yield`, and depending on what other kinds of events may be triggered in those yields, you may have to worry about possible reentrancy problems.

Another approach would be to go ahead and jump into the `MainLoop` and then run the rest of your startup code in a `CallAfter`, or another thread, or whatever makes sense for your application.

Comment: I add `wx.Yield()` right after `splash = AS.AdvancedSplash...` and the behavior is just the same, not solving anything. So going ahead into `MainLoop` means the `class application(wx.Frame)`? What could be a startup code?